# how can i show the avatar image outside the drawer in mui reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, react-hooks, material-ui

i am trying to show the avatar image curve outside the sidebar border line.

i took the persistent drawer from mui v5 as an example and here is [the codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/persistentdrawerleft-material-demo-forked-su6qj?file=/demo.js)

my target is to be like follows [image: which was taken by another google example]

in this example my drawer style is as followed:

```
<Drawer
        sx={{
          width: drawerWidth,
          flexShrink: 0,
          //position: "relative",
          "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
            width: drawerWidth,
            boxSizing: "border-box"
          }
        }}
        variant="persistent"
        anchor="left"
        open={open}
      >
```

and the Avatar's style inside the drawer header as followed:

```
<Avatar
  alt="test"
  src="./test.jpg"
  sx={{
    //position: "absolute",
    width: "120px",
    height: "120px",
    marginLeft: "150px"
  }}
/>
```

how can i achieve such style? please help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following styles

```js
<Drawer
  sx={{
    "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
      position: "relative",
      overflowY: "visible"
    },
  }}
>
```

```js
<Avatar
  sx={{
    position: "absolute",
    top: 20,
    right: -60,
  }}
/>
```

Comment: thanx for your answer but the avatar gets smaller along with the drawer and the avatar is in the middle between drawer and the MuiAppBar+Content main. i want the avatar inside the drawer and the portion of it floating outside of it over the content main.

Comment: Edit `top` and `right` properties to achieve the desired result.

Comment: it works. thanx

Answer (score 1):

Besides setting its position to `absolute`, you need to divide the `Avatar` size by 2, then negate it to move half of the `Avatar` outside of the `Drawer`. See this example:

```
<Avatar
  sx={{
    position: "absolute",
    top: 40,
    right: -60 / 2, // half the avatar size. negate it to move half outsize
    width: 60,
    height: 60
  }}
  {...}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]